# How many rows meet a condition based on permutation of columns in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix where each row is a sample and each column is a species (sample X species matrix). I want to know how many samples (rows) have the same two unspecified species present (positive values). For example:

```
> df <- matrix(c(1,0,10,1,8,1,0,1,0,0,1,0),nrow=4,ncol=3)
> colnames(df) <- letters[1:3]
> df
      a b c
[1,]  1 8 0
[2,]  0 1 0
[3,] 10 0 1
[4,]  1 1 0
```

Here, I have 4 samples where abundance of species a, b, and c are recorded. The tricky part (for me) is I don't care what the two species are. Therefore, I need to permute through every pairwise* combination of columns and have R return the frequency (number of rows) where each pairwise combination was found together (and what they were). Whether the third species is present or not is irrelevant. In this example the answer would be:

a and b co-occur in 2 samples.

a and c co-occur in 1 sample.

b and c co-occur in 0 samples.

I would really appreciate any help or advice to solve this problem. Thank you so much!

*I used 2 species arbitrarily as an example.

Comment: What does this have to do with SQL?

Comment: Please provide the desired result based on your example data

Comment: The desired result was provided: a and b co-occur in 2 samples. a and c co-occur in 1 sample. b and c co-occur in 0 samples. The desired approach is provided below. Than you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `combn`, like this:

```
df <- matrix(c(1,0,10,1,8,1,0,1,0,0,1,0),nrow=4,ncol=3)
colnames(df) <- letters[1:3]
df

combn(colnames(df), 2, FUN = function(x) {
  sum(as.logical(df[, x[1]]) & as.logical(df[, x[2]]))
})
# [1] 2 1 0
```

---

With names:

```
unlist(combn(colnames(df), 2, FUN = function(x) {
  setNames(sum(as.logical(df[, x[1]]) & as.logical(df[, x[2]])), 
           paste(x, collapse = "_"))
}, simplify = FALSE))
# a_b a_c b_c 
#   2   1   0
```

Comment: I always forget about this function!

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly for the two column example and is easily extended to more if desired.